# Regular expression

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm trying to find Strings of length 4 In this regular expression. However, I'm having trouble understanding how the string is built

$$1(1+00)^*0+(01)^*+(101+0)(10+λ)1^*$$

For example,

for $1(1+00)^*0$, if I decide that * gives me 1 or more  I should get $1000$. But if I say * gives me nothing, would that mean that the string is $10$ or is it just $0$? Is my logic correct?

Does the * only affect whats in the brackets or does  it affect everything behind it?

Here's an example string That I came up with (This is in regards to the whole expression):
$$1001$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, the Kleene star oprator $(\cdots)^*$ binds very strongly -- it applies only to the thing *immediately before* it, unless brackets are used to draw more in.

So $1(1+00)^*0$ means "a `1`, followed by zero or more things that are each either `1` or `00`, followed by a `0`".

Your example `1001` is not matched by the regular expression. In particular it is not matched by $1(1+00)^*0$, because that can only generate strings that end with 0.

Comment: Sorry, the example String refers to the longer regular expression

Comment: @DanielMunoz: It is not generated by any of the other components either. The only strings _they_ can generate that start with $1$ have to come from the third component and start with $101$.

Comment: So in regards to $1(1+00)^*0+(01)^*+(101+0)(10+λ)1^*$ what would be an acceptable string providing it has a length of 4?

Comment: @DanielMunoz: Some of them are `1110` and `1000` and `0101` and `1011`.

Comment: @DanielMunoz: The expression is of the form $A+B+C$ which means that each string _has_ to come from $A$ alone, or $B$ alone, or $C$ alone (or perhaps several of these). So not only don't you _need_ to use the entire expression; you _must_ take the summands one at a time and see what they generate.

Comment: Of course, That makes a lot of sense. Could I possibly get 1010 as a string?

Comment: @DanielMunoz: I don't see any way to make `1010`.

Comment: Wouldn't you get: $1(1+00)^*0 = 1$ then $(01)^* = 01$ then $(101+0)(10+λ)1^* = 0$. Why would this not work?

Comment: @DanielMunoz: Because $A+B+C$ does not mean that you can _concatenate_ strings generate by $A$ and $B$ and $C$. You can only get strings that are generated in full by $A$, and also strings that are generated in full by $B$, and also strings that are generated in full by $C$.

Comment: (Also, that's an abuse of equals signs. You don't mean that $1(1+00)^*0$ and $1$ both have the same meaning, right).

Comment: I completely misunderstood the $+$ sign, yes I was concatenating  each string together and now I understand.